# How to automate a table that holds deletions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

So as I have it now, I have a table called Registrant that holds everything that is live. If a user deletes a record, it moves the row to the RegistrantDelete table. The problem is, if I make any edits to the Registrant table (IE a new column) then I have to also make the same edits in the RegistrantDelete table. Is there some easy way to automate this deletion table to be the same setup as the original table?

Comment: Could you have just one table, mark the deleted rows with a flag and a view that shows only non-deleted data?

Comment: You could do as @JamesZ suggested and then create separate views that show non-deleted rows, deleted rows or all rows depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a DDL trigger.   But James' comment of doing "soft deletes" is how I would handle this, personally.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this.

Answer (score 1):

This of mainly for the future. In SQL Server 2016 you could solve this by using a [Temporal table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx)